# Morton-code based Linear BVH: Why do triangle's bounding boxes' centroids give higher-quality trees than triangles' centroids?

Tags: trees

I've implemented [linear BVH as described in Karras 2012](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/), and I was using triangles' centroids for Morton Code generation. I found recent papers and implementations use triangles' **bounding boxes'** centroids for Morton Code generation and they seem to result in better BVHs.

I used triangles' centroids because I didn't know where to start and I saw this paragraph in Karras' HPG paper (page 4):

> BVHs. Following in the footsteps of Lauterbach et al.
> [LGS∗09], we construct a BVH for a set of 3D primitives as
> follows: (1) assign a Morton code for each primitive **according to its centroid**,

But most other implementations and discussion of LBVH use objects' bounding boxes for Morton Code generation:

- AMD's GPURT implementation's [GenerateMortonCode kernel](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Drivers/gpurt/blob/86360020040cbcf69a93addf1a53260ac6e2632b/src/shaders/GenerateMortonCodes.hlsl#L347) uses a Scartch Node's centroid for Morton Code computation. A Scratch Node can contain 1 or 2 triangles.
- MeistDan's [Hippie library](https://github.com/meistdan/hippie/blob/39d781c73ee1124b76ba3061e4f573258146ec10/src/hippie/rt/bvh/LBVHBuilderKernels.cu#L124C48-L124C48) uses AABBs' bounding boxes
- Chitalu's [OI-BVH implementation](https://github.com/chitalu/oibvh-tree/blob/eb1802c8176b82b50ca8b26ae7e260d944ab6a54/shared.h#L67) indicats it uses triangles' BBoxes for Morton Code
- And also [Karras' own article](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/thinking-parallel-part-iii-tree-construction-gpu/) mentions:

  > A good way to assign the Morton code for a given object is to use the centroid point **of its bounding box.**

---

I think I know how to explain the higher quality of triangle bboxes in a "posterior" point of view, i.e. from existing results, but not explaining **why** it is the case. Take "CornellBox" as an example:

1. (Method 1) BVH4 generated for Cornell Box, using triangles' centroids for Morton Code. One can see that triangles that are not just non-coplanar but also far-apart become neighbors on the second-to-last level of the tree, such as (triangle 8, triangle 25), and (triangle 9, triangle 5). An internal node that covers those pairs will waste a lot of space.
   [image: BVH4 generated for Cornell Box, using triangles' centroids for Morton Code]
2. (Method 2) BVH4 generated for Cornell Box, using triangles' AABBs' centroids for Morton Code. One can see triangle pairs forming quads such as triangles 24 and 25, and triangles 8 and 9, have the same parent. This will result in internal nodes that are much more tightly packed.
   [image: BVH4 generated for Cornell Box, using triangles' AABBs' centroids for Morton Code]

I have observed from my rendering program that Method 2's tree is faster to trace, with about **30% fewer ray-box intersections** needed for the same image.

One can also observe that Method 2 results in internal nodes with much smaller surface areas. This corroborates the results form my rendering program.

So far I have seen results but I wonder if there is any formal, closed-form description of why this is the case. Some of my guesses are:

- BVHs are centered around bounding boxes. So starting with bounding boxes might "fit" the algorithm better.
- It has to do with the distribution of the input data: If there are many triangle pairs that form quads, the pairs will share the same centroid, and grouping them at the level above the leaf node level would be the local optimal choice.
- If there are many triangles that are tilted, bounding boxes' centroids may or may not result in worse trees than triangles' centroids.

Any input will be appreciated. Thanks!